# Stating a linear program

Tags: math-mode

I know how to do this the hackish way. However, what would be a more mature and clean way to state a linear program, as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Another_example) on Wikipedia? That is, an expression of the form:

minimize f(x)

subject to

g_i(x) <= 0, for i in {1,...,n}

h_j(x) = 0, for j in {1,...,m}

Comment: Could you describe what you consider hackish?

Comment: Hackish is very ill-defined, I agree. What I mean is using the few keywords I know and small hacks to get something which looks sort of nice. This might (a) take much more time than needed and (b) be very cumbersome to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a short definition I sometimes use in my articles. More like a boilerplate, and you need to change some stuff if you happen to have more constraints. The `\eqnlimit` macro is a shorthand for index ranges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx*\eqnlimit[3][1=1, 3=n]{\ensuremath{#1 \leq #2 \leq #3}}

\newcommand{\linprog}[6]{
    \begin{alignat}{5}
          \label{#6-1}
          \min        & \quad #1 & \\
          \label{#6-2}
          \text{s.t.} & \quad #2 &, & \quad #3\\
          \label{#6-3}
                      & \quad #4 &, & \quad #5
    \end{alignat}}

\begin{document}
    \linprog{f(x)}{g_i(x) \leq 0}{\eqnlimit[1]{i}[n]}{h_j(x) = 0}{\eqnlimit[1]{j}[m]}{eq:linprog1}
    \linprog{f(x)}{g_i(x) \leq 0}{\eqnlimit[1]{i}[n]}{h_j(x) = 0}{\eqnlimit[1]{j}[m]}{eq:linprog2}
    \\
    First linear program\\
    This is the objective: (\ref{eq:linprog1-1}), the inequality constraint set: (\ref{eq:linprog1-2}), and the equality constraint set(\ref{eq:linprog1-3}).
    \\ \\
    Second linear program\\
    This is the objective: (\ref{eq:linprog2-1}), the inequality constraint set: (\ref{eq:linprog2-2}), and the equality constraint set(\ref{eq:linprog2-3}).
\end{document}
```

Thanks to Caramdir for the help with the labelling.

Comment: Thanks. Can one also easily label the conditions "\quad #2 &, & \quad #3\\" and "\quad #4 &, & \quad #5\\" in order to refer to them later on?

Comment: @Jack: Indeed. See revised version.

Comment: @Martin: this is not going to work if you have more than one linear program.

Comment: @Caramdir: Ahhhhh yes, of course you're right. I'm open to suggestions on this then, I'll revert to the previous version.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to add another parameter for the label.

Comment: @Caramdir Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 27):

I would consider the code below as the common way to do that.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    \text{minimize }   & \sum_{i=1}^m c_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n d_j t_j\  \\
    \text{subject to } & \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} + e_j t_j \geq g_j &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n\\
                       & f_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}t_j \geq h_i\ &,\ & 1\leq i\leq m\\
                       & x\geq 0,\ t_j\geq 0\ &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n,\ 1\leq i\leq m
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is at least as good. Would like to mark both as correct.

Comment: Thorsten Donig's solution is actually much more flexible than the current "best" answer, since you are not constrained (as in the definition of \linprog) to have a fixed number of constraint equations. That is, with Thorsten's answer you can simply add more lines in the body of the alignat* if you need more.

Comment: @Johnny: Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that this is not a forum and answer posts are only for solutions to the answer. I converted your post to a comment now. You can't post comments everywhere or up-vote posts yet. This requires reputations points first. See the FAQ and About links on the very top of this page for more information.

Comment: I came to post this method (which is what I use), but Thorsten did it first and did it very well!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot! For what it's worth: in case of having an equal sign in the goal function, I always add a `\quad` after the first ampersand in the lines below.