# Formatting linear programs

Tags: math-mode

When stating LP problems I usually use something along the following

```
\begin{tabular}{ l c p{1pt} c }
max     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$300x + 100y$} \\
s.t.    & $6x + 3y$ & $\leq$ & $40$\\
        & $x - 3y$  & $\leq$ & $0$ \\
        & $x + \frac{1}{4}y$ & $\leq$ & $4$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

But this forces the use of inline math, and require me to adjust column width manually (and it's still not perfect since the spacing between the right hand side and left hand side of `\leq` is wrong).

What I really would like was a solution that allowed for display math, with correct spacing and no need for manual formatting with `p{}`.

How would I write a version that fixes this?

Comment: Something like an `array` environment would probably suffice here (see [the first answer on this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75108/how-to-edit-the-linear-programming-in-latex?rq=1); I don’t have time for a full answer right now).

Comment: A good thing is to read the fine document MathMode.pdf of Herbert Voß.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the wider spacing associated with display-style math, you could use a combination of the `gather*` and `aligned` environments (both provided by the `amsmath` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\max_{x,y}\quad 300x + 100y \\
\begin{aligned}
\textup{s.t.}\quad 6x + 3y  &\leq  40\\
                   x - 3y  &\leq  0 \\
         x + \tfrac{1}{4}y  &\leq  4 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I love it! Even better than I could've imagined!

Answer (score 5):

Using the `array` environment, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
    \max          & 300x & + &         100y &      &    \\
    \mathrm{s.t.} &   6x & + &           3y & \geq & 40 \\
                  &    x & - &           3y & \geq &  0 \\
                  &    x & + & \frac{1}{4}y & \geq &  4
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This gives a proper alignment IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but since of april 23, 2019, exists also a specific package  for the formatting the linear programs named `optidef`, very fast and simple.

I have put the parameter `|s|` (to write only `max` and not `maximize`), and the option `<b>` it is uses for to create a break on the *objective* to have a blank space. Here there is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}


\begin{document}
\begin{maxi*}|s|<b>
{\scriptstyle x,y}{300x + 100y}{}{}%%%% <----objective
\addConstraint {6x+3y}{\leq 40}{}
\addConstraint {x-3y}{\leq  0}{}
\addConstraint {x+\tfrac{1}{4} y}{\leq  4}{}
\end{maxi*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `gather` environment is working well in this example only because the objective function and the constraints have similar sizes.

If you don't need to align the objective function with your constraints, you can nest an `array` in an `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &\mathrm{max} \quad 300x + 100y  \\[2pt] % if you need space between objectif and constraints
    &\mathrm{s.t.} \quad 
    \begin{array}[t]{r c r c r}
         6x & + &           3y & \geq & 40 \\
          x & - &           3y & \geq &  0 \\
          x & + & \frac{1}{4}y & \geq &  4
     \end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have noticed that the `\max` command does not align very well in the `align` environment, I have replaced it by `\mathrm{max}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!